# warnings when using setDelay and addFrameWithFilename

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, warnings, deprecated

I want to use the following lines of code in my project.

```
   // Create the intro image
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    CCSprite *introImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"intro1.png"];
    [introImage setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];
    [self addChild:introImage];

    // Create the intro animation, and load it from intro1 to intro7.png
    CCAnimation *introAnimation = [CCAnimation animation];
    [introAnimation setDelay:2.5f];
    for (int frameNumber=0; frameNumber < 8; frameNumber++) {
        CCLOG(@"Adding image intro%d.png to the introAnimation.",frameNumber);
        [introAnimation addFrameWithFilename:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"intro%d.png",frameNumber]];
```

I get the warning:

```
instance method '-setDelay:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

pointing to the line

```
[introAnimation setDelay:2.5f];
```

and a similar warning pointing to the line

```
[introAnimation addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"intro%d.png",frameNumber]];
```

Has setDelay and addFrameWithFilename been deprecated? If yes, what should I use in their place. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at CCAnimation.h file.  `/** Delay in seconds of the "delay unit" */
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float delayPerUnit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm ... not certain these methods exist at all. Here is an example from my code base (cocos2 version 2.0).

```
+ (CCAnimation *) getAnimationForSoldier:(Soldier *)theSoldier animationType:(mapAnimationTypeE)animationType {

    id animation = nil;
    NSString *animationName = [SpriteUtils getAnimationNameForSoldier:theSoldier animationType:animationType];
    if (!animationName) return nil;
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", animationName]];

    if ((animation = [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] animationByName:animationName])) {
        return animation;
    } else {
        NSUInteger numberOfFrames = 8;
        if (animationType == mapAnimationTypeCast || animationType == mapAnimationTypeSkill) numberOfFrames = 20;
        NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfFrames];
        for (NSUInteger i = 1 ; i <= numberOfFrames ; i++) {
            NSString *frName = [SpriteUtils getFrameNameForAnimationNamed:animationName andFrame:i];
            CCSpriteFrame *frr = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:frName];
            if (frr) { 
               [frames addObject:frr];
            } else {
                MPLOGERROR(@"*** No frame named [%@], bailing out.", frName);
                return nil;
            }
            [frames addObject:frr];
        }

        animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:.06];
        [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:animation name:animationName];

    }

    return animation;

}
```

note : first create your spriteframes array, then create the animation with the array and the desired delay.

The delay is delay between each frame (not the total duration).

If you are using cocos2d version 2.N, the setter for delay is

```
animation.delayPerUnit = 0.6f;
```